# Pattern match for singleton tags only in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, match

Is it possible to have pattern something like `<[a-zA-Z0-9]></[a-zA-Z0-9]>` to match each nodes in xslt stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't want to use regex. Just use a predicate to match tags (elements) that don't contain any child nodes...

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

How do you want to classify elements that only have attributes (like `<foo attr="bar"/>`)?

If you don't want to classify elements that have attributes as a singleton, you would change the predicate to:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(node()) and not(@*)]">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, above predicate will also match empty elements ( like `<foo attr="val"></foo>`). How do I distinguish between them, or is it not possible?

Comment: Yes because `<foo attr="val"></foo>` and `<foo attr="val"/>` are equivalent. There isn't a way to treat them differently in XSLT (because they're not different).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I was not certain about this.  I will have to find another way to fix my issue, xslt won't help then.